# Selenium trouble finding button

Tags: selenium, automation, css-selectors

I have the following code snippet:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnov9.png)

I am trying to select the button download in the page:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj5F7.png)

I am using the following code

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import datetime

d_ref = datetime.date.today()

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\\User\\Download\\chromedriver.exe')

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

prefs = {'download.default_directory' : 'D:\\User\\Download' }

chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)

driver.get('https://www.anbima.com.br/pt_br/informar/sistema-reune.htm')

# driver.maximize_window()

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 320);")

driver.switch_to.frame(0)

# driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Dt_Ref").clear()

# driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Dt_Ref").send_keys(d_ref.strftime('%d%m%Y'))

dropdown = driver.find_element(By.ID, "TpInstFinanceiro")

dropdown.find_element(By.XPATH, "//option[. = 'C F F']").click()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "fieldset:nth-child(3) input:nth-child(1)").click()
```

Comment: Should not post an image of code instead of a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS-selector `fieldset:nth-child(3)` is highlighting `Financial Instrument` and `fieldset:nth-child(3) input:nth-child(1)` is not highlighting any element in the DOM. [Link to refer](https://automationpanda.com/2019/01/15/web-element-locators-for-test-automation/)

Below CSS-selector is highlighting the Download option in the DOM.

```
fieldset:nth-child(5) input:nth-child(4)
```

Better to close the Cookie pop-up to interact with other elements. Use Explicit waits.

```
# Imports
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://www.anbima.com.br/pt_br/informar/sistema-reune.htm")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,20)

# Click on Proceed on the Cookie pop-up
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@class='LGPD_ANBIMA_global_sites__text__btn']"))).click()

# Switch to Iframe
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class]")))

# Select Download option
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"fieldset:nth-child(5) input:nth-child(4)"))).click()
```